# Bug with PHP file upload into MySQL mediumblob

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, blob, multipartform-data

I have a script that is meant to allow a user to upload files of type DOC, DOCX, PDF and TXT. Files do get uploaded, albeit without line breaks. So for instance,  a TXT files like this:

```
//////////
THIS IS A TEXT FILE
//////////
```

gets downloaded back as:

```
//////////THIS IS A TEXT FILE//////////
```

Now this is not such a "big" issue with text files but this loss of line breaks completely corrupts PDF, DOC and DOCX types.

Again, a PDF viewed in Notepad originally looks like this:

```
%PDF-1.5
%µµµµ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-US) /StructTreeRoot 10 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
....
```

However, after uploading and then downloading, it looks like one long string with some characters gone missing:

```
%PDF-1.5%µµµµ1 0 obj<>>>endobj2 0 obj
```

Hence, when opening the file in Adobe PDF reader, it says it is corrupted.

---

This is an excerpt of the PHP script I am using to upload the file:

```
$_POST['request_id'] = $_POST['rid'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['exam_file']['tmp_name'];
    $_POST['name'] = $_FILES['exam_file']['name'];
    $_POST['type'] = $_FILES['exam_file']['type'];
    $_POST['size'] = $_FILES['exam_file']['size'];
    //File types allowed are PDF, DOC, DOCX, TXT
    if ( ( $_POST['type'] == "application/pdf") || ($_POST['type'] == "application/msword") || ($_POST['type'] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") || ($_POST['type'] == "text/plain") ){
        $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        fclose($fp);
        $file_id = $model -> addFiles($_POST, $content);    
    }
```

---

The function addFiles() in $model is as follows:

```
function addFiles($data, $file){
    $table = 'faculty_files';
    $data = parent::clean($data);
    $keys = array('request_id', 'name', 'type', 'size', 'content');
    $data = parent::cleanAndPick( $keys, $data );
    $data['content'] = $file;
    $data['faculty_user_id'] = $_SESSION['user_details']['id'];
    $data['inserted_on'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    parent::insert( $table, $data );
    return mysql_insert_id();
}
```

`parent::insert()` just takes all the relvant details such as table name and fields and puts them into a SQL statement.

This is the function `parent::clean()` although `$file` is not being run through it:

```
public function clean($data = NULL){
  $data = str_replace("\n", "", $data);
  $data = str_replace("\r", "", $data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}
```

Function `parent::cleanAndPick()`

```
public function cleanAndPick($keys, $data = NULL) {

    $clean = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $data))
            $clean[$key] = $this -> clean($data[$key]);
    }
    return $clean;

}
```

Function `parent::insert()`

```
protected function insert($table, $data ) {

    //Build sql
    $data = $this -> clean($data);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $this -> clean($table);
    $sql .= " (" . implode(",", array_keys($data)) . ") VALUES (";
    foreach ($data as $value)
        $sql .= ($value == NULL ? "NULL," : "'" . $value . "',");
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -1) . ")";
    return $this -> query($sql);

}
```

---

This is  the PHP script I am using to download the file:

```
$file = $model -> retrieveFile($_POST['fid']);
header("Content-length: " . $file[0]['size'] . "");
header("Content-type: " . $file[0]['type'] . "");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=" . $file[0]['name'] . "");
print $file[0]['content'];
```

---

I have no idea what is causing this problem. I would appreciate any input!

EDIT: Someone had a similar problem on the [PHP forum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). An excerpt:

> I have been trying unsuccessfully to upload and read a Mac OS file on
>   a Linux server. Lots of records show up a just one big using only the
>   following:

```
<?php $fhandle = fopen($file, 'r'); ?>    or  <?php $fhandle =
> fopen($file, 'rb'); ?>
```

> It does work, however, this way:

```
> <?php  ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);  $fhandle =
> fopen($file, 'r');  ?>
```

I did try this and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Seems that something has 'eaten' the line delimiters or translated them to UNIX (\n) Can you open the file in notepad++? Do you see linebreaks?

Comment: No line breaks in Notepad++

Comment: Even if you enable UNIX style line delimiters?

Comment: can you output `$content`? Does it look ok? (linebreaks) ?

Comment: check the byte size of the blob v.s. the bite size of the original. if something is eating the line breaks during/after the upload, the blob should be smaller. Note that fread **MAY** translate line endings for you, if you don't supply the `b` option to read it in binary (non-translated) mode.

Comment: outputting $content doesn't have line breaks either. Which probably suggests that the upload is the problem as opposed to the download?

Comment: Last comment can be easy answered. If you check files content in the database using phpmyadmin (or whatever) .. Do you see line breaks?

Comment: No line breaks in MySQL Workbench

Comment: If this is not a 'display error' (make this sure, eventually using a hexeditor) .. then it's a problem with the upload. Btw: I coded a PHP hexdump library it should be useful in this case. Check it, it may help : https://github.com/metashock/Hexdump .. Would be interesting to see if the delimters aren't there if after fread().. Would like to see `hexdump($content);`

Comment: ... If they are present after upload, then I would using `hexdump($content)` at every postion in code where $content will be touched. If it's not the upload that breaks the file (unlikely) then I assume it's a problem with the MySQL query (or the datatype that is used for it)

Comment: Using `stripslashes` is a sign your server is configured incorrectly, "magic quotes" should not be on. Using `mysql_query` is considered harmful, it's a deprecated interface scheduled to be removed from future versions of PHP. Using PDO would be a much better idea. This `insert` function you have is terrifying, it's very difficult to tell if everything is correctly escaped because of your `clean` wrapper method. Additionally, arbitrarily removing `"\r"` from your input seems damaging when dealing with binary data.

Comment: But I am not remvoing `"\r"`. `$file` is not being run through any of these functions. I have not written this code- I am just working under a certain infrastructure that is beyond my control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fopen($tmpName, 'rb');` if you don't want any change to its contents.

And then this:

```
protected function insert($table, $data ) {
  //Build sql
  $data = $this -> clean($data); //<---- here......
```

Comment: Added cleanAndPick, insert and clean

Comment: `$data = parent::cleanAndPick( $keys, $data );` is run before I state that `$data['content'] = $file;` so `$data['content'] = $file;` is untouched no?

Comment: Is it okay to run `$file` through `mysql_real_escape_string()`? Without it, I get an error in the SQL...

Comment: Yep, perfectly fine, by it's nature, it should preserve the data as is (when used in a query that is).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25621/discussion-between-karancan-and-wrikken)